Random Effects v.s. Random Design Matrix
It is commonly explained that a random effect is used when the values of the variable associated with the random effect are drawn from a population, such as schools in the sample out of schools in the entire country, while a fixed effect is used when the values of the associated variable are not random i.e they represent the entire population.
This explanation seems quite wrong to me. First it is common practice when interpreting fixed effects to generalise them to values beyond those observed in the sample. And second, if the values of the random effects variable are drawn from some population, why aren’t the values themselves modelled as random, but the effects are?

Hover over the statistics tag and read that popup

I think the random-effects setting can be recast within the random-design setting. For instance suppose the Z matrix coincides with the X matrix in the random-effects setting and assume it is the normal mixed linear model. In that case a typical component in the random-effects setting looks like:
x(fixed-parameter + N(0,var)) = N(x*fixed-parameter, x * var * x^t)

On the other hand in the normal random-design setting, a typical component looks like:
fixed-parameter(x + N(0, var)) = N(x*fixed-parameter, fixed-parameter * var * fixed-parameter^t)

In both settings, we want to estimate fixed-parameter and the covariance matrix var.  With a change of variables for the covariance matrix var, we can jump between these two specialized settings.
